# Create combinedshape using GeometryGroup in Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need some help with my code. combineShape.Freeze() function looks not working well.

In this scenario I have two radio button, named rbtPoint and rbtLine. When I click rbtPoint and click on the canvas it will create a point and now I have to create 2 points (ellipse1, ellipse2) in the canvas, in this step I already able to drag the Point (either ellipse1 or elipse2) around the canvas. Then when I click on rbtLine then click the first point (ellipse1) it will change the color of point from red to blue, then when I click again on the 2nd point (ellipse2) it will change the color to red as well and it will create connecting blue line from ellipse1 to ellipse2.

After that the line and 2 points will be combined into 1 shape using GeometryGroup() function. I saw the code from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417950/combining-linegeometry-with-ellipsegeometry-in-code-not-xaml) here on StackOverflow.

Here is my code to create the function:

```
private void myCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown  = true;
    initialPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);

    if (rbtPoint.IsChecked == true)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is Ellipse)
        {
            captured = true;
            shapePoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
            clickedEllipse = (Ellipse)e.OriginalSource;
            uielement = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
        }
        else
        {
            shapeEllipse = new Ellipse();
            (shapeEllipse as Ellipse).Width = 30;
            (shapeEllipse as Ellipse).Height = 30;
            (shapeEllipse as Ellipse).StrokeThickness = 5;
            (shapeEllipse as Ellipse).Fill = Brushes.Red;
            Canvas.SetLeft(shapeEllipse, initialPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(shapeEllipse, initialPoint.Y);
            myCanvas.Children.Add(shapeEllipse);
        }
    }
}

private void myCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(null);
    captured = false;
    mouseDown = false;
    if (rbtLine.IsChecked == true)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is Ellipse)
        {
            captured = true;
            initialPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
            clickedEllipse = (Ellipse)e.OriginalSource;
            uielement = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
            poin = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(uielement);
            clickedEllipse.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            if (firstpoint.X != 0 && firstpoint.Y != 0)
            {
                lineEndPoint = initialPoint;
            }
            else
            {
                firstpoint = initialPoint;
            }
        }

        if (lineEndPoint.X != 0 && lineEndPoint.Y != 0)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
            shapeLine = new Line();
            (shapeLine as Line).X1 = firstpoint.X;
            (shapeLine as Line).Y1 = firstpoint.Y;
            (shapeLine as Line).X2 = lineEndPoint.X;
            (shapeLine as Line).Y2 = lineEndPoint.Y;
            (shapeLine as Line).Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
            (shapeLine as Line).StrokeThickness = 5;
            myCanvas.Children.Add(shapeLine);
            lineCreated = true;

            var ellipse1 = new EllipseGeometry(firstpoint, firstpoint.X, firstpoint.Y);
            var ellipse2 = new EllipseGeometry(lineEndPoint, lineEndPoint.X, lineEndPoint.Y);
            var line = new LineGeometry(this.firstpoint, this.lineEndPoint);

            GeometryGroup combinedShape = new GeometryGroup();
            combinedShape.Children.Add(ellipse1);
            combinedShape.Children.Add(ellipse2);
            combinedShape.Children.Add(line);

            combinedShape.Freeze();
        }   
    }
}
```

After I run combinedShape.Freeze() function, when I click again on one of the Point and drag it, it only move the clicked point without the other point and line following my mouse movement.

How to solve this problem? I have found many articles related but most of them they do the code in XAML not code behind. Or is there any other way to solve this?
I need suggestion for this problem,

Thank you for your help, code masters..

Fikri

Comment: Did you check this article? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750593%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you don't really want to freeze it.  Freeze() makes the geometry unchangeable, which is exactly why it doesn't change.

The only other option is to do something like clone() the frozen geometry, and then delete the frozen one.

```
private void myCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown  = true;
    initialPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);

    if (rbtPoint.IsChecked == true)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is Ellipse)
        {
            captured = true;
            shapePoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
            var frozen = (Ellipse)e.OriginalSource;
            clickedEllipse = frozen.Clone();
            myCanvas.Children.Remove(frozen);
            myCanvas.Children.Add(clickedEllipse);
            uielement = (UIElement)clickedEllipse;
        }
        else
```